# Umask: group permissions effect on files and directories

Tags: permissions, umask

If I changed my "umask", so that **group** members had all permissions.

What would be the effect when creating new files and directories?

Answer (score 0):

The effect depends on the application.

When an application creates a file it specifies the **maximum** amount of permissions that should be granted. The umask says which of those permissions should be **actually** granted.

So if you have a umask of 0770 saying that group members should not have any permissions restricted and the application says that the file should have 0600 (so r/w to owner and no group or other permissions) then the file ends up 0600. If the application said it should be 0666 (r/w to owner, group and other) then the file ends up 0660.